# Standard interpretation of permanents (of orthogonal included) over finite fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, finite-fields, permanent

Given a $0/1$ matrix in $\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$ the standard interpretation of permanent of the matrix is the number of perfect matchings in the underlying $2n$ vertex balanced bipartite graph with biadjacency given by the matrix.

Suppose we are given a square matrix $U$ with entries in $\mathbb F_{p^t}$ which is a finite field of characteristic $p>2$.

1. What is the standard interpretation of permanent in these scenarios?
2. Suppose the matrix is orthogonal is there a standard interpretation?

Is there reference?

Comment: Trivially: The matrix can have any entries, corresponding to a graph with weighted edges. Then the permanent is the sum of the weights of perfect matchings, where the weight of a perfect matching is the product of the weights of its edges.

Comment: I am looking for an interpretation for the number we get after reduction in absolute terms.